# How to throw an error from an async mongoose middleware post hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

What's the correct way to throw an error from an async [Mongoose middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) **post hook**?

#### Code Example

The following **TypeScript** code uses mongoose's post `init` event to run some checks that are triggered whenever a function retrieves a doc from mongoDb. The `postInit()` function in this example is executing some background checks. It is supposed to fail under certain circumstances and then returns a `Promise.reject('Error!');`

```
schema.post('init', function (this: Query<any>, doc: any) {
    return instance.postInit(this, doc) 
    .catch( err => {
        return err;
    });
});
```

The hook works fine. I.e. the following code triggers the hook:

```
MyMongooseModel.findOne({ _id : doc.id}, (err, o : any) => {
    console.log(o);
});
```

However, if `postInit()` fails, the error isn't passed back to the calling function. Instead, the document is returned.

#### Expected behavior

I'm looking for the right way to pass this error to the calling function. If the background checks fail, the calling function shouldn't get a document back.

I have tried different ways to raise this error. E.g. `throw new Error('Error');`. However, this causes an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`  and still returns the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose maintainer here. Unfortunately, `init()` hooks are synchronous and we haven't done a good job documenting that. We opened up a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6747) and will add docs on that ASAP. The only way to report an error in `post('init')` is to `throw` it.

```
const assert = require('assert');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const GITHUB_ISSUE = `init`;
const connectionString = `mongodb://localhost:27017/${ GITHUB_ISSUE }`;
const { Schema } = mongoose;

run().then(() => console.log('done')).catch(error => console.error(error.stack));

async function run() {
  await mongoose.connect(connectionString);
  await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();

  const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
  });
  schema.post('init', () => { throw new Error('Oops!'); });

  const M = mongoose.model('Test', schema);

  await M.create({ name: 'foo' });

  await M.findOne(); // Throws "Oops!"
}
```

This is because Mongoose assumes [`init()` is synchronous internally](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-init).

Answer (score 0):

In this **post init hook** method you only receive a **doc**:

**Document.prototype.init()**

> Parameters doc «Object» document returned by
>   mongo Initializes the document without setters or marking anything
>   modified.
>
> Called internally after a document is returned from mongodb.

Mongoose Documentation: [Init HookDocumentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-init)

And for trigger a error you need a done or next method:

**Post middleware**

> post middleware are executed after the hooked method and all of its
>   pre middleware have completed. post middleware do **not directly** receive
>   flow control, e.g. **no next or done** callbacks are passed to it. post
>   hooks are a way to register traditional event listeners for these
>   methods.

Mongoose Documentation: [Post Middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/unstable/docs/middleware.html)

If you only want to know if happened a error in your call, change for this:

```
MyMongooseModel.findOne({ _id : doc.id}, (err, o : any) => {
      if(err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }

      console.log(o);
    });
```

If you want to propagate the error one option is use a **pre** hook method:

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  const err = new Error('something went wrong');
  // If you call `next()` with an argument, that argument is assumed to be
  // an error.
  next(err);
});

schema.pre('save', function() {
  // You can also return a promise that rejects
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject(new Error('something went wrong'));
  });
});

schema.pre('save', function() {
  // You can also throw a synchronous error
  throw new Error('something went wrong');
});

schema.pre('save', async function() {
  await Promise.resolve();
  // You can also throw an error in an `async` function
  throw new Error('something went wrong');
});
```

Example Error Handling: [Error Handling](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)